# Are RLS policy definitions affected at runtime by the search_path?

Tags: postgresql, roles, row-level-security, search-path

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69697986/1048572), I gave some (unfounded) advice on

```
create policy test_policy on policy for all to public using (
        user_id = session_user_id());
```

> Btw, you should schema-qualify the `session_user_id()` call to make your policy actually secure, so that the user cannot inject their own `session_user_id` function through the `search_path`.

But is this actually the case? I had misremembered [the `search_path` issue with `SECURITY DEFINER` functions](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/abusing-security-definer-functions/).

How and when are row-level-security policies parsed? Are the references resolved during definition or during evaluation?

It would make sense to have identifiers in them be early-bound not late-bound, but I could not find anything in the docs about this.

Comment: Take a look at [RLS policies](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-rowsecurity.html) four paragraphs down starting with "To specify which rows ..." and see if that answers your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver No, it doesn't - that only talks about how and when the expressions are evaluated, not when they are being parsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Policy definitions are stored in [`pg_policy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-policy.html), where the `USING` clause is stored in the `polqual` column and the `WITH CHECK` expression is stored in `polwithcheck`.

Both columns are of data type `pg_node_tree`, which is a parsed SQL statement. So policies are parsed when they are created, not when they are executed, much like views or standard conforming SQL functions (new in v14). That means that the setting of `search_path` is only relevant when the policy is created, not when it is executed.